# Tuning the query SELECT COUNT(1)

Tags: mysql

Cant we reduce the time taken by the "`SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE T1 WHERE...`"  with the below conditions....

1. Query is scanning a partition (this is observed in the EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT)
2. Query is using the primary key
3. Query is scanning 25 Mill rows.

Regards,
RAM

Comment: Thanks gbn, I will keep improving on this. I am very new to this.

Comment: "count(*)", not "count(1)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Innodb, we cant improve the performance of SELECT COUNT(*) query.
The only alternative is to have counter tables and triggers or some other way of implementations to update these.

Regards,
UDAY